# Should you make FK the index of another table?

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

I have this simple table

[image: table]

that has type has FK and name has PK.

My problem is that type is the index of the type instead of the actual string. So when I add a `TestCase` to the database I have to give the index instead of simply write the String type.

Does Hibernate have implemented functionality to do this or do I have to do another query to check what's the index that corresponds to that typeName?

```
 public static void addTestCase(String testName, String type, MultipartFile file, String user) {
    byte[] fileByte;
    Date date = new Date();
    final DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    String creationDate = sdf.format(date);

    try {
       fileByte = file.getBytes();
        TestCase testCase = new TestCase(testName,type,fileByte,creationDate,user);
        Database.addToDatabase(testCase);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

TestCase

```
public class TestCase {

private int id;
private String name;
private String type;
private byte[] data;
private String creationDate;
private String createdBy;

public TestCase() {
}

public TestCase(String name, String type, byte[] data, String creationDate, String createdBy) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.data = data;
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
}

...get and setters
```

xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.atp.Model.TestCases.TestCase" table="testCases">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
        This class contains the testCases details.
    </meta>
    <id name="id" type="int" column="idtestCase">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
    <property name="type" column="type" type="string"/>
    <property name="data" column="data" type="binary"/>
    <property name="creationDate" column="creationDate" type="string"/>
    <property name="createdBy" column="createdBy" type="string"/>
</class>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems to be a oneToMany relationship (many test cases to one type). Check how to do that in hibernate for instance in [onetomany example](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many).

Basically, your testCase object should have a type object rather than just a simple string and this object should have JPA or hibernate annotations.

Basically,

Your type in TestCase should be an object:

```
 private Type type;
```

You should create a class *Type* with a testcase set:

```
 private Set<TestCases> testCases;
```

Your type.hbm.xml should have:

```
<set name="testCases" inverse="true" cascade="all">
     <key column="TYPE_ID" not-null="true" />
     <one-to-many class="TestCase"/>
</set>
```

And your testcase.hmb.xml should have:

```
<many-to-one name="type" class="Type"
        column="TYPE_ID" not-null="true"/>
```

Comment: To be honest Im not using any annotation. Just the .hbm.xml files.

Comment: So, then, search for an example using hgbm.xml configuration. However, It still needs to be a oneToMany relation

Comment: Here there is a good example https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example/. You have to change the type from string to List<object> and change your hbm.xml type

Comment: Can you please help me on this? I just started on this. Can you provide an example for my problem?

Comment: I'm getting Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.atp.Model.TestCases.TestCase column: idtestCase (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Comment: seems like you changed to TYPE_ID now

Comment: I did everything like you said but I get java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'idtestType' in 'field list'

Comment: Which is the id column name in class Type mapping?. You should have specified the id column name in the hbm. The error says it doesn't exist

Comment: Please check my full code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48113649/unkown-column-x-in-field-list