# Unkown column x in field list

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to create a one to many relation between two tables. TestCase has a FK called Type

Basically many testCases can have one type but a testCase can only have one type.

What am I missing here?

[TestCase table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dD9tl.png)

[TestType table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS1Pg.png)

But I'm getting

> Unkown column idtestType in field list

Model

```
public class TestCase {

private int id;
private String name;
private TestType type;
private byte[] data;
private String creationDate;
private String createdBy;

public TestCase() {
}

public TestCase(String name, TestType type, byte[] data, String creationDate, String createdBy) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.data = data;
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
}
```

TestCase.xml

```
    <hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.atp.Model.TestCases.TestCase" table="testCases">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
        This class contains the testCases details.
    </meta>
    <id name="id" type="int" column="idtestCase">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
    <many-to-one name="type" class="com.atp.Model.TestCases.TestType" fetch="select">
        <column name="idtestType"/>
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="data" column="data" type="binary"/>
    <property name="creationDate" column="creationDate" type="string"/>
    <property name="createdBy" column="createdBy" type="string"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Model

```
public class TestType {

private int id;
private String desc;
private Set<TestCase> testCases = new HashSet<>(0);

public TestType() {
}

public TestType(String desc, Set<TestCase> testCases) {
    this.desc = desc;
    this.testCases = testCases;
}
```

TestType.xml

```
   <hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.atp.Model.TestCases.TestType" table="testType">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
        This class contains the testCases details.
    </meta>
    <id name="id" type="int" column="idtestType">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="desc" column="desc" type="string"/>
    <set name="testCases">
        <key>
            <column name="idtestType" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.atp.Model.TestCases.TestCase" />
    </set>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Trying to add it to the database

```
 public static void addTestCase(String testName, String type, MultipartFile file, String createdBy) {
    byte[] data;
    Date date = new Date();
    final DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    String creationDate = sdf.format(date);
    TestType testType = new TestType();
    testType.setDesc(type);

    try {
       data = file.getBytes();
        TestCase testCase = new TestCase(testName,testType,data,creationDate,createdBy);
        testType.getTestCases().add(testCase);
        Database.addToDatabase(testCase);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: hello darkness my old friend...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a

```
idtestType
```

column in the TestCase table.

Or, if you want to use the `type` column in the existing table your TestCase.xml-Mapping is wrong and should be

```
    <many-to-one name="type" class="com.atp.Model.TestCases.TestType" fetch="select">
    <column name="type"/>
</many-to-one>
```

(column is "type" instead of "idtestType")

Comment: now I get: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc) values ('UI')' at line 1

Comment: ´<property name="desc" column="desc" type="string"/>´  ... desc is a reserved word, I'd pick some other column name ...

Comment: ´select x from y order by z desc´ i guess? ;)

Comment: there's a problem. I only have 3 times (1,2,3) and in the table it added type 4 http://prntscr.com/hwfe3u

Comment: That's how you've impemented your code (new TestType()) ... and also quite another question ...

Comment: Im getting a String with the type from the front end. Now I want to add the index of that type to the database. So in this case I get string `UI` and I want to get index 1. Can you please help me on this?

Comment: Then you've got to read that TestType from the Database and assign it to the TestCase ... not create a new one everytime the method is called ... I'd suggest reading up on some hibernate tutorials on how to do queries etc.